# Unable to Launch calculator through Appium on windows 10 shown error

Tags: android, appium

When I am trying to launch calculator on android through appium installed on windows 10 error marked in bold is shown.kindly help

info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s NTIO030423 install "C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"

> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s NTIO030423 install "C:\Program Files\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s NTIO030423 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s NTIO030423 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg  com.android.calculator2 -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   **error: Unhandled error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at errnoException (dns.js:49:15)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26) context:** [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":" com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Moto G","platformVersion":"6.0"}}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when ur path is not set properly. very ur PATH variable and ANDROIDHOME @varunnadim

Answer (score 0):

This is because its not able to resolve dns name...

Make sure you add your dns server addres in your network config..

If you are using localhost then you need active internet connection to resolve into valid ip...in this case check your internet connection